# Given 1 boolean input and N boolean outputs, how many different functions can be formed

Tags: logic, boolean-logic

A function accepts 1 input and has 2 outputs. The 1 input is T or F and N outputs are all either T or F. How many different functions can I create.

I got 2^(N + 1) but seems wrong. It might be 2^2^n. Not sure how to prove it

Comment: (2^N)^2, which simplifies to (4^N). In general, the cardinality of the function space from domain A to domain B is `|B|^|A|`. Here, your `|B|` is `2^4`, and |A| is `2^1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single output, there are four functions:

```
F0(x) = 0
F1(x) = 1
F2(x) = x
F3(x) = !x
```

Accordingly, there are `4^N` different functions with `N` outputs. Imagine a N-digit number with base `4`.